# Alamofire DataRequest has no serializingDecodable

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I trying alamofire concurrency async/await calls but it seems some methods is not available especially serializingDecodable. I am using alamofire 5.6

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-swift-concurrency

Also any concrete example to use alamofire concurrency on a iOS swiftui app? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `serializingDecodable`, you may not be using the required version of Xcode, 13.3+. Older versions of Xcode won't show the concurrency APIs at all.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Xcode 13.2 . but i can use async and await, it is weird though that the serializingDecodable don't show up.

Comment: There are significant bugs in Xcode 13.2's concurrency implementation, so 13.3+ was made the requirement. You can use Alamofire 5.5 if you really want to try the feature out, but 5.6 with Xcode 13.3+ is recommended.